# Speed of sound in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

The speed of sound varies in different fluids https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sound-speed-liquids-d_715.html

Can the value be derived from other physical parameters -- vapour pressure, viscosity etc. -- or can it only be determined experimentally?

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0id2jJML9_E) might be helpful. It has the derivation.

Comment: In short, it depends on the bulk modulus and the density of the fluid. Note that in case of gas, it depends on the adiabatic index, pressure and density.

Answer (score 1):

Like anything involving waves, the key to getting the speed of sound waves is solving the wave equation for the fluid, which is the same as calculating the restoring force (see [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus)) of any displacements in that fluid.

Thus for an ideal gas, you can calculate this theoretically:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma RT}{m_{}}}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic factor (degrees of freedom) and m is the mass of each molecule.

You must rely on experiment beyond that to the extent of which your gas is *not* an ideal gas for precisely the same reasons - but of course there are good quasi-theoretical approximations for those that can be calculated.